# Flutter: How to change a value of a variable in another dart file?

Tags: flutter, dart, variables, themes

I have a problem, when I want to change a theme from dark to light mode (vice versa) i couldn't change the theme from a different dart file.

For example, I have a switch button on the appbar of the same file. This way, I can change my theme just by clicking it.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:experimental/drawer.dart';

bool isSwitched = true;

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: isSwitched
          ? ThemeData(
              brightness: Brightness.dark,
              backgroundColor: Colors.black,
              appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
                  titleTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
                  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                  elevation: 0),
              colorScheme: ColorScheme.dark(
                primary: Color.fromARGB(255, 58, 29, 7),
                secondary: Colors.black,
              ),
              drawerTheme: DrawerThemeData(
                shadowColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                elevation: 0,
              ),
              iconTheme:
                  IconThemeData(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 184, 137, 33)),
            )
          : ThemeData(
              brightness: Brightness.light,
              appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
                  titleTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                  iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                  elevation: 0),
              colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(
                primary: Color.fromARGB(255, 153, 119, 92),
                secondary: Colors.white,
              ),
              drawerTheme: DrawerThemeData(
                shadowColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                elevation: 0,
              ),
              iconTheme:
                  IconThemeData(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 184, 137, 33)),
            ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("this is title"),
          actions: [
            Switch(
                activeColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 184, 137, 33),
                value: isSwitched,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    isSwitched = !isSwitched;
                  });
                }),
          ],
        ),
        body: Center(
            child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Text(
              'this is text',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
            Icon(Icons.ac_unit_outlined),
          ],
        )),
        drawer: DrawerWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The problem is, i have a different dart file which i will put a switch button and use it for changing the theme, but the theme doesn't change.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:experimental/main.dart';

class Settings extends StatelessWidget {
  const Settings({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: null,
      appBar: AppBar(
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(
          color: Colors.grey,
        ),
        title: Text(
          'Settings',
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(0, 48, 48, 48),
        elevation: 0,
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          ListTile(
              title: Text(
                "Dark Mode",
              ),
              leading: Icon(
                Icons.dark_mode,
              ),
              trailing: SwitchExample()),
          ListTile(
            title: Text(
              "About Us",
            ),
            leading: Icon(
              Icons.privacy_tip_outlined,
            ),
            trailing: new Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                new Container(
                  child: new IconButton(
                    icon: new Icon(
                      Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      // Navigator.push(
                      //   context,
                      //   MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const About()),
                      // );
                    },
                  ),
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SwitchExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const SwitchExample({super.key});

  @override
  State<SwitchExample> createState() => _SwitchExampleState();
}

class _SwitchExampleState extends State<SwitchExample> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Switch(
        activeColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 184, 137, 33),
        value: isSwitched,
        onChanged: (value) {
          setState(() {
            isSwitched = !isSwitched;
          });
        });
  }
}
```

How do i fix it?

I'm expecting so I can change the theme from a different dart file.

Comment: Your problem is not about changing the value of the global variable; that's trivial: just do `isSwitched = yourNewValue;`.  However, after you change the variable, you must *rebuild* your `Widget`s so that they use the new value.  Consider using a [`ValueNotifier`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ValueNotifier-class.html) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### This is how to go about this problem.

- Using `bool` will not solve this problem.
- And this is where `ValueNotifier` and `ValueListenableBuilder` come in.
- Declare your `isSwitched` variable as a `ValueNotifier<bool>`

```html
ValueNotifier<bool> isSwitched = ValueNotifier<bool>(false);
```

##### NB: It should be outside of the widget, declare it just after `imports` in order to access it globaly

- Wrap your `MaterialApp` widget with a `ValueListenableBuilder<bool>`

```html
return ValueListenableBuilder<bool>(
 valueListenable: isSwitched,
 builder: (context, value, child) => MaterialApp(
  theme: value
      ? ThemeData(
          brightness: Brightness.dark,
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
              titleTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              elevation: 0),
          colorScheme: ColorScheme.dark(
            primary: Color.fromARGB(255, 58, 29, 7),
            secondary: Colors.black,
          ),
          drawerTheme: DrawerThemeData(
            shadowColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            elevation: 0,
      ),
          iconTheme:
              IconThemeData(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 184, 137, 33)),
        )
      : ThemeData(
          brightness: Brightness.light,
          appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
              titleTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
              iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              elevation: 0),
          colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(
            primary: Color.fromARGB(255, 153, 119, 92),
            secondary: Colors.white,
          ),
          drawerTheme: DrawerThemeData(
            shadowColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            elevation: 0,
          ),
          iconTheme:
              IconThemeData(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 184, 137, 33)),
        ),
        )
      // Other attributes
  );
```

- Then, update your `onChange(){}` event in the Switch widget like so

```html
Switch(
   activeColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 184, 137, 33),
   value: isSwitched.value,
   onChanged: (newValue) {
       setState(() {
            isSwitched.value = newValue;
         });
 }),
```

##### If you want to know more about `How to add dynamic theming to flutter apps`, kindly check this [nice article](https://baimamboukar.medium.com/dynamic-theming-in-flutter-using-hive-e9d59527f440)

#### Happy Codding

Answer (score 0):

Try to use state management and put the variable in the controller. Then your entire app can write, listen, etc from a "state". In this case, the state is "isSwitched"